# Isset not recognizing external variable

Tags: php, mysqli, isset

First off, because this is my first question, thanks to all the contributors, this community has helped me immensely as I've worked my way through the various issues I've encountered as I am a novice developer.

So the issue I'm facing is pretty odd to me. I've included the complete code below minus the html as it works fine. In the code I declare a couple of variables, the $userID which is set from the $_SESSION['user'] which is what I use to id the user currently logged in. This works on many other pages just fine. I also declare the $groupID variable which is set from the $queryString, the query string is simply the groupID passed from the previous page, nothing fancy. This issue I run into is when I try to run the buttons pay fee and or update team name.

For some reason the $userID is being passed properly but the $groupID is not. I know the syntax is correct because if I manually place a groupID in the query it works, however it does not when I try to call the $groupID variable. This seems to only happen when running an UPDATE query and works fine with INSERT and SELECT and DELETE but doesn't seem to want to work for UPDATE.

My question is, why would this happen, why can my code see one variable that has been declared but not the other? And why does it work in other types of queries but not this one? As I said I am new to this so there may be something to the UPDATE query that I don't yet understand. I appreciate any guidance you all may offer.

```
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

// if session is not set this will redirect to login page
if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

// find out the domain:
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// find out the path to the current file:
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
// find out the QueryString:
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// put it all together:
$url = "http://" . $domain . $path . "?" . $queryString;

$groupID=$queryString;
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$userID=$user;
$error=false;

// pay fee, in progress
if ( isset($_POST['btn-payfee']) ) {

    if( !$error ) {
    $query = "UPDATE membership SET paid = '1' WHERE userID='$userID' AND groupID='$groupID'";
    $res9 = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if (!$res9) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
    }

    if ($res9) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Account successfully updated";
            //header("Location: dashboard.php");

        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";   
        }   
    }
}

// update team name
if ( isset($_POST['btn-updatename']) ) {

    // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
    $teamName = trim($_POST['teamName']);
    $teamName = strip_tags($teamName);
    $teamName = htmlspecialchars($teamName);

    // if there's no error, continue to signup
    if( !$error ) {

        $query = "UPDATE membership SET teamName='$teamName' WHERE userID='$userID' AND groupID='$groupID'";
        $group = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if ($group) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Account successfully updated";
            header("Location: fantasy-group.php?451f70f10dfab9b3b4a12683cef850a5");

        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";   
        }   
    }
}



        <!-- change team name -->               
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="on">
                <label class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" for="inlineFormInput">Team Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="teamName" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $row2['teamName']; ?>" maxlength="32" / >
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="btn-updatename">Update Name</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: `$groupID = $queryString;` doesn't seem right. It should be something like `$groupID = $_GET['groupid']`

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` may not be populated on `POST` requests. Since that is your basis for $queryString, can you `var_dump()` that inside one of your `isset($_POST[...]))` checks to see if there's anything in it?

Comment: It doesn't but I actually echo the code out in the document and it shows that the variable is set properly.

Comment: Query strings are usually in the form `param1=value1&param2=value2&...`. These are parsed into the values of `$_GET['param1']`, `$_GET['param2']`, etc.

Comment: this block (after `$res9`) will never execute: `else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
        }`

Comment: If you're doing a POST, the query string would have to be in the form's `action` URL. Can you show what the form looks like?

Comment: Yea, but my application is simple and the only thing I needed from the string was a single ID the groupID so my string looks like this.

group.php?451f70f10dfab9b3b4a12683cef850a5 

This lets me manage static features on the page just by knowing what ID was passed from the previous page and comparing that to the logged in user and the membership table from the database.

Comment: I added the form to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Pedro, that executes if it's something I've already done. It's redundant i know, but it helps me test.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Did you get any warning or error? that will help us to identify the error.

Comment: Not getting any errors unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're populating **$groupId** with the entire query string. You need the parameter from **$_GET**, **$_POST** or **$_REQUEST**. For example: **$_GET['group_id']**, **$_POST['group_id']** or **$_REQUEST['group_id']**.

Also, you are trying to pass unfiltered, unescaped user input into a database query which is vulnerable to *sql injection*. You will want to look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and also filtering your input. Example:

```
$groupID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "group_id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I get what you're saying, however the way I have things coded, on the previous page when you click a link to view a group it passes the url with a querystring with the ID of the group you're looking to view. so the URL would look something like this.

fantasy-group.php?451f70f10dfab9b3b4a12683cef850a5

That Id gets set to the $queryString variable which in other instances has worked perfectly fine when I set it with $groupID = $queryString; and then echo it out to the page directly (just for testing). So far everything has worked perfectly except in this case.

Comment: On the same page I use the $groupID variable to make other calls to the database for other reasons and there are no issues. Just when I try to call $groupID from within the isset function. And for some reason the same function calls the $userID variable perfectly fine. This is where I'm confused. I read through your example and I'm not certain how to apply it here. Or maybe you can suggest a better route for what I'm trying to do. 

Unfortunately I can't call the database for this ID i need it passed from another page for this feature to work properly. If that makes since.

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] isn't going to work when the request method is POST. I've never seen query strings used in this manner. I'd suggest assigning your value to a variable so that you can use the standard $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST (to handle both GET and POST requests.) This will be far more flexible if you need more data to your forms later on. The request via get should look similar to http://<mydomain>/fantasy-group.php?group_id= 451f70f10dfab9b3b4a12683cef850a5

Comment: That makes sense. I do have have one last question before I go try that. Since after the page loads I do actually assign the querystring value to the groupID variable, which should effectively avoid any complications and seems to work perfectly for queries like

$res2="SELECT groupID, userID, groupName, teamName FROM membership WHERE userID='$userID' AND groupID='$groupID'";

on the same page. Why would it behave differently when being called in isset? and why would $userID not have an issue? 

echo "<p>".$queryString;"</p>";
echo "<p>".$groupID;"</p>";
echo "<p>".$group_ID;"</p>";

Comment: When I echo the various variables to the page they seem to be populated perfectly fine. So I guess I'm just not understanding why it would work in the $res2 query and why it wouldn't work in the isset query.

Comment: The page loads via a GET request. Your isset checks are looking for POST, which has no way to acquire the query string unless you pass it from a form with a method set to POST.

Comment: You can see how this works if you setup a simple form: 

<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input name="test">
    <button type="submit">
</form>

<?php print_r($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); // Undefined index: QUERY_STRING

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="on">

This is my form action, how would I change this to pass the string properly. I tried simply changing this to send the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] but that didn't work.

Comment: You can use a hidden input field: <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">

Comment: Sorry, I meant QUERY_STRING. Ideally you would populate this from elsewhere though, like from the database resultset or session.

Comment: You sir are a gentlemen a scholar and just awesome, that worked perfectly. Thank you so much.